# How to register RedisModule in Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs

I've followed the instruction from [nestjs-redis documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis) to register RedisModule but it gives me the following error message. I am new to Nest.js and have no idea how to fix this error.
If you know the better way to use Redis with nestjs, please suggest me.

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RedisCoreModule
> (Symbol(REDIS_MODULE_OPTIONS), ?). Please make sure that the argument
> ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the RedisCoreModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current RedisCoreModule?
> - If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RedisCoreModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]   })

my app.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RedisModule.register({
      host: `${host}`,
      port: 6379,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: try to use this other lib instead https://github.com/nest-modules/ioredis it's well maintained.

Comment: btw if your host value is dynamic, then you must use `.forRootAsync`. Read more about async providers here: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/async-providers#asynchronous-providers (I advise you to read the entire Nestjs docs)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this @liaoliaots/nestjs-redis package instead of nestjs-redis. Follow the structure of this link https://github.com/liaoliaots/nestjs-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/latest/redis.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34018592)